# Kitchen faucet low flow rate?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I have a kitchen faucet with a single handle separately on the side.

The sprayer flows fine but the faucet flows only at about 60% of the sprayer rate. I removed the airator but no change to the flow.

The faucet did flow a lot more before I installed a pressure reducer on the water main. Understandably that would lower the flow some but it lowered the flow much more at this faucet than others. Others seem to be flowing at full cross sectional area of the pipe. The
is one looks like 75%.

Any ideas what it could be causing this?

I had to replace the valves on my fridge water dispensor. Looked like the seals had been compressed by the high water pressure I had before. Could a similar thing be the cause in my kitchen faucet?

The handle connects to the faucet through a line and the sprayer connection comes off on the side of that line at the faucet connection. See attached image.

[image]

[Image of the faucet I have.](https://images.pfisterfaucets.com/is/image/WebAssets/pf_marielle_lg26-4nss_c1-sp?wid=600&qlt=80&resMode=sharp&fmt=png-alpha)

Update:
So I pulled the handle appart and took out the cartridge. At the bottom of the handle assembly there are 3 holes and three other holes below them. These holes don't line up though. See image. Is that the way they are supposed to be? I need to look into if those can be aligned.
[image: handle]

Comment: Is this a **change**, or just the way it's always been - there might be no "fix" if it's set up to give more force from the sprayer than the faucet.

Comment: Thanks I should have included additional info. Just updated the post with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was the diverter that is in line with the faucet.

The valve inside the diverter is stuck down. It only moves a little up when the faucet is running. The valve in the downward position supplies water to sprayer which is why the sprayer was fine.

Interestingly if you cycle the sprayer on and off a few times the valve loosens some and can move upward more which lets some more water flow through the faucet for a period of time.

$14 for new diverter.

[image]

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Thanks for coming back to share your knowledge and for clicking the check mark.